# Is there a way to parse jsonp on server side in angular universal?

Tags: node.js, ajax, angular, jsonp, angular-universal

I have a site built with angular2 which requests data from a 3rd-party server. I'm also using angular universal to render pages on server side. And here comes the problem: parsing jsonp relies on dom operations, which is not available on server side. So I can only get static pages without data.
Is there a way to parse jsonp on server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsonp

There are much more modules on npm. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=jsonp

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I forget searching npm! However I have asked the remote server to enable CORS so I don't have to use jsonp. I will try your suggestion later. Thank you all the same :-)